# AWS Lambda CloudWatch log streams missing in action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

From the what I've read, there is supposed to be a CW log stream per container.
I have a system that calls hundreds of Lambda (same Lambda function) concurrently (via SNS).
I only see 10-20 log streams each time. AFAIK it's supposed to be only one Lambda per container, so it doesn't add up.
Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here's a quote from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/ '... if you haven’t changed the code and not too much time has gone by, Lambda may reuse the previous container.'

Comment: @Tartaglia is right. If you don't update the code, CloudWatch logs are stored in the same stream most of the times.

Comment: @Tartaglia, but even if I haven't changed the code, when the Lambdas run concurrently, it means they are using multiple containers (again, under the assumption that one Lambda runs in one container). Can multiple containers write to the same log stream?

Comment: If you see multiple invocations in those twenty log streams (instead of one invocation each for 100 log streams), then it means it is not running concurrently as you may think. Can you include in your question how you call Lambda concurrently via SNS?